# How to rewrite or proxy url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker

I am new in nginx. I want to rewrite

```
feature-1234.mydomain.com/xyz?foo=bar
```

to

```
docker-feature-1234:9000/xyz?foo=bar
```

with request parameters.

I use official nginx docker image. How should be my nginx.conf file?

**EDIT**: 'feature-1234' is a variable so:

```
feature-5678.mydomain.com
```

should serve as

```
docker-feature-5678:9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By combining answers, i found the solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/388552/nginx-sub-domain-proxy-pass

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here

nginx.conf:

```
events {
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~(.*).test.go;

    location / {
      if ($host ~* ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.test\.go$) {
        set $proxyhost docker-$1:9000;
      }

      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
      proxy_pass http://$proxyhost;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

site.conf

> server_tokens off;
>
> map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {   default upgrade;   ''
>   close; }
>
> server {
>
> set $access_log 'var/log/nginx/my-site.access.log';   set $error_log
>   'var/log/nginx/my-site.error.log';
>
> listen 80;   server_name feature-1234.mydomain.com;
>
> access_log /$access_log;   error_log /$error_log;
>
> location / {
>
> ```
> proxy_pass docker-feature-1234:9000;
>
> proxy_http_version 1.1;
> proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
> proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
> proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
> proxy_set_header Host $host;
>
> if ($uri != '/') { expires 30d;}
> access_log /$access_log;
>
> } }
> ```

paste it on

> touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf

next

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

next

> service nginx reload

if you don't root access add sudo to beginning of the commands

Comment: thanks for the answer but i updated the question to be more clear. Feature name will be variable. Can you review your answer?